# Positive integration on P^1

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-dynamics

Let $u: \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function s.t. $u$ is invariant under complex conjugation and $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})}u \; \omega_{\mathrm{FS}}=0$. Assume $u \not\equiv 0$.

I want to find an integer polynomial $f(z)$ s.t. $f$ is "small" in the sense that $|f(z)| \leq (1+|z|^2)^{\deg(f)/2}$ and $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})} u\; f^*\omega_{\mathrm{FS}}>0$.

For example if we take $f$ be a small integer polynomial and consider the $n$-th iteration $f^n$, then $\frac1n f_n^*\omega_{\mathrm{FS}}$ would weakly converges to the equilibrium measure $\mathrm{d}\mu_{J(f)}$ of the Julia set $J(f)$ of $f$. So particularly, if we can find $f$ s.t. the integration $\displaystyle \int u \mathrm{d}\mu_{J(f)}>0$, we win.

My thought is, consider a sequence $f_n$ of small polynomials of degree $n$, $\frac1n f_n^*\omega_{\mathrm{FS}}$ is bounded so we have a convergent subsequence. If in some way we can design this sequence properly so that the integration of $u$ w.r.t. the limit measure is positive, we win.

This problem arises in my study but unfortunately I do not know much complex analytic geometry. I appreciate any random thoughts or comments.